# Unioning from a variable number of tables. (Overloaded stored MySQL Procedure)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a 10 tables with the same schema. I'm trying to create an *overloaded* stored procedure so that I can union a bunch of tables together with simple selects (SELECT * FROM tableX). If each table has 1000 (different) rows, then I want to create a stored procedure where the following would happen:

```
CALL getRowsByNum(table1); -> 1000 rows
CALL getRowsByNum(table1, table2, table4); -> 3000 rows
```

...etc.

I got part of the way through writing 10 overloaded procedures that would `SELECT * FROM X UNION ALL SELECT * FROM X UNION ALL`..... etc, but that's really **madness**.

Anyone have a different suggestion? This silly setup is the result of an architectural decision made a while ago.

Thanks!

Comment: redesign the crazy architectural, painful but helpful

Comment: I had a feeling someone would say that... the "overloaded" bit is so that it plays nice with a visualization app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can't have variable number of parameters or procedures with the same name.

I dont think there is an easy solution to your problem.

EDIT: I've thought of an really ugly solution but I'll leave it to you if you wanna use it. This is untested pseudo code only.

Create a proc where you take a varchar in, long enough to hold the value "table1,table2,table3,..." and so on for as many tables you like to union at most. (could be another identifier of course)

Write all tables in union. Since they are the same just use * to save time and space

```
delimiter //

create procedure megaunion (tables varchar(255)) 
begin 
   select * from table1 where find_in_set('table1', tables)   
   union
   select * from table2 where find_in_set('table2', tables)
   ....
end//
```

list all your tables. At least you don't have to list the possible permutations and the user of the procedure won't know how you did it :)

Comment: No. All procs and functions are stored in mysql.proc and the primary key is is on db, name and type so you can use the same name twice per database. One for the proc and one for the function.  Also, functions can't return resultsets.

Comment: I've added a "ugly" solution as well

Comment: Will probably have to get creative refactoring DB workflow, like you said, but thanks for the potential short-term solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree that you have to rethink your db structure.
By the way, just for fun :)

```
drop database if exists my_test;

create database my_test;

use my_test;

create table table1 (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
my_field varchar(10)
) engine = myisam;

create table table2 like table1;
create table table3 like table1;
create table table4 like table1;
create table table5 like table1;

insert into table1 (my_field) values ('aaa'),('bbb');
insert into table2 (my_field) values ('ccc'),('ddd'),('eee');
insert into table3 (my_field) values ('fff'),('ggg');
insert into table4 (my_field) values ('hhh'),('iii'),('jjj');
insert into table5 (my_field) values ('kkk'),('lll');


delimiter //
drop procedure if exists tables_union //
create procedure tables_union (in str varchar(10000),in db varchar(100))
begin
set @qry = (select group_concat(concat('select * from ',table_name) separator ' union all ')
            from information_schema.tables
            where find_in_set(table_name,str) 
            and table_schema = db);
-- select @qry;
prepare stmt from @qry;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;            

end; //
delimiter ;

call tables_union('table4,table3,table1','my_test');

+----+----------+
| id | my_field |
+----+----------+
|  1 | aaa      |
|  2 | bbb      |
|  1 | fff      |
|  2 | ggg      |
|  1 | hhh      |
|  2 | iii      |
|  3 | jjj      |
+----+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```